# How to remove script tag in _document on dev mode in Next.js

Tags: next.js

In my next.js app I have _document.tsx with such code

```
   <Head>
      <script
         dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `some GTM script`
         }}
      />
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.ico" />
   </Head>
```

How can I make this code not to work in whil developing, but work when I build project (I use `next build && next export`)

Answer (score 2):

Use `process.env.NODE_ENV` which is automatically available in NextJs.

```js
<Head>
  {process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && (
    <script
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `some GTM script`,
      }}
    />
  )}
</Head>
```